# Rearranging an R list

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list structured as such.

```
list(
    a = list(
        a1 = c(1, 2),
        b1 = c(2, 3)
    ),

    b = list(
        a1 = c(3, 4),
        b1 = c(4, 5)
    )
)
```

What clever use of core R functions, without apply's or recursive functions, can I use to transform it to the following?

```
list(
    a1 = list(
        a = c(1, 2),
        b = c(3, 4)
    ),

    b1 = list(
        a = c(2, 3),
        b = c(4, 5)
    )
)
```

Using stack() drops the inner indices.
Using unlist() merges both indices together.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are trying to avoid `*apply` functions?

Comment: Why would you think that this is such a common transformation that a base function would exist for it? Why are you so concerned to avoid *apply functions?

Comment: I don't believe a single base function exists. There are enough clever data reshaping base functions, however, that it seems reasonable that some combination would work.

Comment: nrussel, I'm avoiding apply functions for the same reason I gave MrFlick. I would like to see how this can be done without it.

Comment: Names are lost, but what about: `split.default(do.call(cbind, L), seq_along(L))`?

Comment: This keeps the outer indices but not the inner indices.(function(x) split(x, f = row.names(x)))(do.call(cbind, test))
Although internally split is a for loop.

Comment: With your last comment, do you really expect that there are no for loops in R's reshaping functions? What's your ultimate objective?

Comment: The reason behind my inquiry is to see if it could be done with the base R "reshaping" functions without explicitly using a loop. Furthermore, I wanted to see if it could be done without using the string splitting fuvctions

Comment: @T-Wayne, OK, so why restrict usage of the `apply` family? They aren't *explicit* for loops. The `reshape` function uses different members of the `apply` family and several for loops. I guess that's out too. And perhaps you should edit your question to mention that functions for working with strings are also not allowed.

Comment: Heellllppp! `unlist` also uses members of the `apply` family!

Comment: Oh no! `stack` does too!

Comment: @T-Wayne - if you use `unlist(x, recursive=FALSE)` you will not recurse past the first level.

Answer (score 2):

OK. Here's an attempt:

```
L1 <- stack(unlist(L, recursive = FALSE))
L2 <- cbind(L1, do.call(rbind, strsplit(
  as.character(L1$ind), ".", fixed = TRUE)))
c(by(L2[c("values", "1")], L2[["2"]], 
   FUN = function(x) split(x[["values"]], x[["1"]])))
# $a1
# $a1$a
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $a1$b
# [1] 3 4
# 
# 
# $b1
# $b1$a
# [1] 2 3
# 
# $b1$b
# [1] 4 5
```

I've wrapped the output of `by` with `c` to remove the `by`-related `attributes` and return the output to a basic `list`.

Comment: clever. split-apply-combine.

Comment: `by` is another `apply` wrapper, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, `tapply`. And the last time I checked, it was a pure sin to use functions that exist for a particular reason. What's going on with the questions these days?

Comment: I think the OP is Richard Scriven with a fake account :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with people wanting to learn the language. :)

Comment: @RichardScriven I'm not against learning the language, but the purpose should be well-defined and the rules should also be clear. In this case, they aren't at all clear nor well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of the fact that the list is an  `environment` , and use `within`.

`x` is the list.

```
> within(x, { a$b1 <- b$a1; b$a1 <- a$b1-1 })
$a
$a$a1
[1] 1 2

$a$b1
[1] 3 4


$b
$b$a1
[1] 2 3

$b$b1
[1] 4 5
```

Here are some other things that might be of interest  Not sure why people seem to steer away from the base R funcions. They are **very** useful in these types of problems (and they make all of Ananda's loops work  ;-).

Did everyone forget about recursive concatenation...

```
> str(x)
List of 2
 $ a:List of 2
  ..$ a1: num [1:2] 1 2
  ..$ b1: num [1:2] 2 3
 $ b:List of 2
  ..$ a1: num [1:2] 3 4
  ..$ b1: num [1:2] 4 5
```

From `str(x)` alone, you can plan the route down the list.  In your list, it's a `[2:1][1:2]` reversal.  By the way R is vectorized!

These things are also useful..

```
> do.call("names", list(c(x)))
#[1] "a" "b"
> do.call("names", list(c(x,recursive=TRUE)))
#[1] "a.a11" "a.a12" "a.b11" "a.b12" "b.a11" "b.a12" "b.b11" "b.b12"
> do.call("c", list(c(x,recursive=TRUE)))
#a.a11 a.a12 a.b11 a.b12 b.a11 b.a12 b.b11 b.b12 
#    1     2     2     3     3     4     4     5 
> do.call("c", list(c(x,recursive=TRUE,use.names=FALSE)))
#[1] 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5
> do.call("as.expression", list(c(x)))
# expression(a = list(a1 = c(1, 2), b1 = c(2, 3)), b = list(a1 = c(3, 4), b1 = c(4, 5)))
> do.call("as.expression", list(c(x,recursive=TRUE)))
# expression(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5)
```

You'll want to do some kind of recursion, the `.Primitive` functions are coded entirely in C and they're not slow by any means.

Here I'm at ground level with the vectors you want to change.

```
> c(x,recursive=TRUE)[3:6]
# a.b11 a.b12 b.a11 b.a12 
#     2     3     3     4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m <- do.call(rbind, ll) ;m2 <- split(m, col(m))  # that transposes the data
names(m2) <- names(ll[[1]])        # these two steps "transpose" the names
lapply(m2, setNames, names(ll) )

$a1
$a1$a
[1] 1 2

$a1$b
[1] 3 4


$b1
$b1$a
[1] 2 3

$b1$b
[1] 4 5
```